# Google Form Responses Reset every month

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am creating a google Form backed with a google Spreadsheet.
Every day, responses will be added to the Form. 
Theses responses are added into the Spreadsheet.

The first responses takes the first line in the Spreadsheet, the second response takes the seconds lines and so on.

When I delete the Form responses and I and an other, it continues like if the previous line of the Spreadsheet were filled.

For example, if I had 4 responses, the last one will be on the row 4 of the Spreadsheet. If I clear the response and add an other, it will be added on the 5th row (while the 4 previous row are empty).

Is it a way to reset the "index" for the new responses after I cleared them?

Here is my Google App Script to do so :

```
 var financeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(_spreadsheetId);
 var financeForm = FormApp.openById(_formId);
 var expencesSheet = financeSheet.getSheetByName(_sheet);

 // Clean the form and the responses
 financeForm.deleteAllResponses();
 expencesSheet.getRange(2, 1, 100, 5).clear();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the script simply "clearing" all data from rows with `clear()` method call. If you want to make sure the row is removed from the `Spreadsheet` structure, use the `deleteRow()` or `deleteRows()` method.

P.s. Although `getLastRow()` may lead you to believe otherwise if you tested for number of rows with it, documentation clearly states that it counts only *rows with content*, thus skipping the ones emptied by `clear()`.

**Clarification**

Perhaps my answer wasn't clear enough on why you should address `SpreadsheetApp` instead of the `FormApp`. The issue here is that you *retain the number of rows* in the Sheet when you call the `clear()` method and Forms always submit the response *to the next row after the last one* **regardless** of whether it contains data or not (this is why "it continues like if the previous line of the Spreadsheet were filled" - there are **placeholder rows** left with no data in them).

**Test**

You can see the difference for yourself by running this function (`getMaxRows()` method returns every row regardless of its content):

```
function getNumRows() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var initial = sh.getMaxRows();
  Logger.log('Initial number of rows: '+initial);

  sh.appendRow(['test']);

  var plusOne = sh.getRange(sh.getMaxRows(), 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  plusOne.clear();

  var cleared = sh.getMaxRows();
  Logger.log('Number of rows after clearing: '+cleared);

  sh.deleteRow(sh.getMaxRows());

  var deleted = sh.getMaxRows();
  Logger.log('Number of rows after deletion: '+deleted);

}
```

**WYSIWYG**

If you still do not believe me, here is the sample I created and tested your case on - as you can see, the result differs depending on using the `deleteRow()` method or `clear()` and has nothing to do with the form being reset or not (I do not invoke the `deleteAllResponses()` method at all).

[image]

**Useful links**

1. `deleteRow()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRow(Integer));
2. `getLastRow()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow);
3. `getMaxRows()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxRows());
4. `clear()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear());

Comment: My question is possibly not clear, my problem is related to the FormApp. The SpreadSheepApp behave as expected. The sheet containing the form reponses get cleaned. But the actual problem is when a new responses is added, it is inserted in the wrong place in the Sheet.

Comment: @Benoit, no, I do understand your question correctly. Please, modify your code and see for yourself - the reason why new responses are added like you described lies in `clear()` usage and has nothing to do with the `FormApp` itself. I even created a sample Form to test it. I apologize in advance if you tried what's been proposed and still get the issue! 
There are no "indexes" in a Form that make it post to a specific row (each response simply adds +1 row) and it is successfully reset with `deleteAllResponses()`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand the effect of deleteRows, it works and the result is better than I thought, I don't have empty lines and the form automatically creates the lines when needed!

Comment: Not at all! This is not obvious that rows are actually kept in place after you clean them of data. Glad I could help!